# Java: Compare Date.getTime with a different date

Tags: java, date, unix-timestamp

There is the date `date1` given with the format `YY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS`
I want to compare

```
date1.getTime()
```

with one retrieved by doing

```
new Date().getTime()
```

There is

```
SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("YY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS");
Date date1 = sf.parse(date1AsString);
...
compare date1.getTime() with new Date().getTime();
```

How can I bring these two dates to a common 'timezone' to compare them?
How can I obtain date1 to be on the same 'time length' as new Date()? I want to have the same timezone...
Thanks

Comment: A `Date` does not have a timezone.

Comment: ok, but how can I compare these values?

Comment: `new Date().compareTo(date1)` perhaps? It's not clear what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: They are two `long` values. Do you know how to compare numerical values?

Comment: if I do new Date().compareTo(date1) will this be done on the same timezone?

Comment: **A `Date` does not have a timezone.**

Comment: but how does simpledateformat parse the string if not by using a timezone?

Comment: `date1AsString` must contain timezone information otherwise you cannot compare them.

Comment: @Roxana Both of your questions have been confused. I suggest you search StackOverflow for "java date" and do some study. Your questions may come into focus once you become familiar with how date-time computation works. Key ideas: • A java.util.Date object has no time zone yet it's `toString` method applies the JVM’s current default time zone (yes, confusing and misleading). • The java.util.Date/.Calendar/java.text.SimpleDateFormat classes are notoriously troublesome and confusing. Avoid them and use either [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or java.time instead.

Answer (score 1):

From the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) of `Date`

> The class `Date` represents a specific instant in time, with millisecond precision.

An instance in time is agnostic of our definition of time enhanced with time zones. **Right now** is the same for you and me, regardless of the fact that we are (potentially) in different time zones.

What adds the notion of a time zone is the [`DateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html)

> The date is represented as a `Date` object or as the milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.

When you invoke [`Date#getTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime--), you get back

> the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT represented by this `Date` object.

This is something you can use to compare `Date` objects since they have the same root. Similarly, the [`compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo-java.util.Date-) will return

> the value 0 if the argument `Date` is equal to this `Date`; a value
>   less than 0 if this `Date` is before the `Date` argument; and a value
>   greater than 0 if this `Date` is after the Date argument.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot compare two dates if their timezone information is unknown.

For example if your `date1AsString` variable is simply `2014-12-16 16:00:00` then you cannot tell if it is greater than or less than `2014-12-16 20:00:00+0000`.

It looks like first date is 4 hours less than second one; but if someone adds that the first date is Pacific Time (UTC-0800) then it would actually be 4 hours more than the second date (`2014-12-16 16:00:00-0800` = `2014-12-17 00:00:00+0000`).

So, if `date1AsString` has an unknown timezone then you cannot convert it to UTC or anything else for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

`getTime()` Returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00 :00. You will want to compare the two `long`s, roughly like so:

```
long time = new Date().getTime();
long time2 = date1.getTime();
if(time>time2)
    System.out.println(String.format("time is greater than time2 by %d", time-time2)
else
    System.out.println(String.format("time2 is greater than time by %d", time2-time)
```

Comment: Timezone wise, how do you know which timezone to use? Date1 for instance may be EST already and you may try converting it to EST again skewing your results. If you have both timezones stored with the dates, simply do some arithmetic to determine the difference in time between timezones.

Answer (score 0):

if you know Timezone 
date1.setTime(date1.getTime()+/-(3600000*hours)) to convert, if date1 time is GMT to go to GMT+2 hours must be 2 and sing must be +

Comment: Only if he doesn't need second resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Typically any server environment is going to be using GMT so you wont have to worry about the timezone when comparing dates, only when formatting the value to be display to users.

You can compare two dates like so:

```
SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("YY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS");
Date date1 = sf.parse(date1AsString);

boolean isBefore = date1.before(new Date());
boolean isAfter = date1.after(new Date());
```

Alternatively, you can compare the numeric values of the unix time to get the same result:

```
...

boolean isBefore = date1.getTime() < new Date().getTime();
boolean isAfter = date1.getTime() > new Date().getTime();
```

Answer (score -1):

The `Date` Class has methods like `before(date)` and `after(date)`. You should take a look into the `Date` Class.

Comment: ok, but how does simpledateformat make the conversion to date? how can I make sure it is the same time?

Answer (score -1):

So I think what you are looking for is to set the time zone of the SimpleDateFormat:

```
sf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
```